# Updating FILESTREAM field record data

Tags: sql-server

What happens with related files on a disk? Do they get deleted and replaced with new files. Or do they get themselves overwritten. Or they remain and new files are simply created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once a row is update in a table which has FILESTREAM enabled, the row
>   will be get updated immediately within the table and the new
>   FILESTREAM data file will be available within the FILESTREAM Data
>   Container. However, there are scenarios when both the original
>   FILESTREAM data and the new FILESTREAM data will remain within the
>   FILESTREAM Data Container. This generally happens as FILESTREAM
>   Garbage Collector process has not run once the row was updated. The
>   old FILESTREAM data will be removed from FILESTREAM data container
>   once the next CHECKPOINT occurs and the garbage collector process has
>   completed successfully. If you want to trigger the FILESTREAM Garbage
>   Collector thread EXPLICIT, then execute the CHECKPOINT command
>   manually.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1850/using-insert-update-and-delete-to-manage-sql-server-filestream-data/